# "No apps can perform this action" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, image-cropper

I am using [this](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) library to crop images in Android Studio. My code works on my phone, but on the emulator when you need to select an image, I see message "no apps can perform this action". [This message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Baj.png). Maybe the problem in my code?

```
userImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CropImage.activity().start(getContext(), SettingsFragment.this);
            }
        });
```

onActivityResult

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                imageUri = result.getUri();
                userImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
                uploadImage(imageUri);
            }
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I didn`t find any information to solve this problem. I tried give permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install file manager on the emulator, as third party app to support the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you use scheme to start an app , your phone or simulator must have at least one app support your scheme. Otherwise you'll get wrong result.